# Azure Machine Learning add_conda_package will fail when the package has name starts "python"

Tags: python, python.net, azure-machine-learning-service

I tested to run my pythonnet based wrapper code on Azure Machine Learning.
I tried add pythonnet package with conda_dependencies property, but it cause some errors.

```
env = Environment(name="env")
env.python.conda_dependencies.add_conda_package("pythonnet")
```

This code will report

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str


~\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\azureml\core\conda_dependencies.py in add_conda_package(self, conda_package)
    461                 if conda_package.startswith(PYTHON_PREFIX):
    462                     python_version = self._get_version(conda_package)
--> 463                     self.set_python_version(python_version)
    464                 else:
    465                     self._conda_dependencies[PACKAGES].append(conda_package)

~\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\azureml\core\conda_dependencies.py in 
set_python_version(self, version)
    418                 if self._python_version != version:
    419                     # Doing an inplace update to preserve the comment above this field in the file.
--> 420                     self._conda_dependencies[PACKAGES][index] = PYTHON_PREFIX + '=' + version
    421             else:
    422                 self._conda_dependencies[PACKAGES].append(PYTHON_PREFIX + '=' + version)
```

I understand azureml code uderstand both package name and "python ..." case. It causes this error.
Does anyone know any work around ?

Comment: The workaround until the fix is out could be to instantiate CondaDependencies from a yaml file.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I will try authoring in yaml.

Answer (score 2):

The work around could be to instantiate CondaDependencies from a yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

I found dumb work round :

```
env.python.conda_dependencies.add_conda_package(" pythonnet")
```